# How to Convert Days into Years Months and Days in datastage?

Tags: date, datediff, datastage, date-difference, transformer-model

I need to calculate age in form of year , Month and date format in Datastage transformer

```
Example       : SERVICE_DT = 02 Mar 1990
                Current date= 22 Aug 2019
Output        : 29 years 5 months 20 days
```

I have developed following formula in DS Transformer

```
((DaysSinceFromDate(DSJobStartDate,TrimSpaces.SERVICE_DT))/365) :' Years ':( Mod(DaysSinceFromDate(DSJobStartDate,TrimSpaces.SERVICE_DT),365)/30):' Months ': mod( Mod(DaysSinceFromDate(DSJobStartDate,TrimSpaces.SERVICE_DT),365),30):' Days'
```

`DSJobStartDate=Current date` 
The above formula is not working well because for 
service date 1997-08-25 it is populating 22 Years 0 Months 1 Days but the correct output is 21 years 11 months 28 days

```
((DaysSinceFromDate(DSJobStartDate,TrimSpaces.SERVICE_DT))/365) :' Years ':( Mod(DaysSinceFromDate(DSJobStartDate,TrimSpaces.SERVICE_DT),365)/30):' Months ': mod( Mod(DaysSinceFromDate(DSJobStartDate,TrimSpaces.SERVICE_DT),365),30):' Days'
```

service date 1997-08-25 it is populating 22 Years 0 Months 1 Days but the correct output is 21 years 11 months 28 days

Comment: There is no ready to use function available and it gets complicated because of leap years. I suggest to look for an OS/script/programming that supports this functionaliyt and use it through DataStage

Answer (score 0):

You formula didn't take into consideration with years having 366 days as well as assuming months and days are based on 30.

This is the link to the functions - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_Date_and_Time_Functions.html

For example DaysSinceFromDate suppose to be replace by DaysSinceFromDate2 from V11.3 onwards.

You may want to consider using YearFromDate, MonthFromDate and MonthDayFromDate instead.